# Make Win10 account local without the password

Tags: windows-10, local

Hey so im trying to make a Microsoft account a Local account, I dont have the password to the account but I do have the PIN, So i can login to the account.

I do have Admin access

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a Microsoft account and forgot the password, but still remember the PIN, you need to reset your password online from Microsoft website.

Step 1: sign in to Windows 10 with the PIN.

Step 2: Open the browser, go to https://account.live.com/password/reset, and follow the screen to reset your Microsoft account password.

Once you change your password, you can remove the connection to a Microsoft account any time. Here's how:

Open Settings > Accounts and click Your info.
After confirming that the account is set up to use a Microsoft account, click Sign in with a local account instead.
Enter the password for your Microsoft account to confirm that you're authorized to make the change, and then click Next.
On the Switch To A Local Account page, enter your new local user name and password, along with a password hint.
Click Next to sign out from the Microsoft account and sign back in using your new local account.
This change doesn't affect any files or installed Windows desktop programs.